# How to Play Videos Files from an iPod Video Library?

Tags: iphone, video

How can I play video files in my application from an iPod video library? Is there any other possibility to search and play video files stored anywhere in an iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

You can't The iPod Library access is audio only at this time. There is currently no way to access any video outside of your application sandbox (in other words, you can only search through and play video your app has downloaded itself).

If you need access to the video library you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug with Apple describing why you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can play video files store in device, there are 3 places you can search :

1. Camera Roll : video recorded
2. iPod Library
3. File Sharing

After searching on internet I found this sample of Apple describe how to get and play those videos.
Here is [AVPlayerDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Hope this will help you. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**MPMediaPropertyPredicate** *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMovie] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [query items];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]init];
for (MPMediaItem* item in items)

{

```
  //get the Title of video

  NSString* title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
  NSLog(@"title %@",title);

   //get the path of Video
    url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSLog(@"url %@",url);
```

}